# Representing a tagged union / sum type in Varlink

Tags: c++, serialization, sum-type

There’s a structured type *T* that I need to pass over a
[Varlink](https://varlink.org/) socket that has a field with a collection of
elements of the same type. The latter can be one of three concrete types. In
C++ the type is defined as a tagged union similar to this pseudo code:

```
enum Discr { Int, Bool, String };

struct T {
    string name;
    enum Discr discr;
    union {
        vector<bool>    b; // if .discr is Bool
        vector<int>     i; // if .discr is Int
        vector<string>  s; // if .discr is String
    } data;
};
```

In C++ the validity of accesses is enforced at runtime by member functions; the
corresponding Rust implementation does it at the type level. So far so good.

Now for my question: What would be the idiomatic possibly most ergonomic way of
representing this kind of type (which is a rather common pattern!) in a Varlink
API?

Varlink does have an `enum` construct but it seems to be as limited as the
C++ / C one. Varlink however lacks a `union` counterpart that would allow
defining tagged unions so its enums are quite useless in practice. The only
true variant type it has is the `Nullable` type which itself can’t be defined
in the Varlink DSL.

Comment: `std::variant<vector<bool>, vector<int>, vector<string>>` (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: @m88: ``std::variant<vector<bool>, vector<int>, vector<string>>`` — how does
that help expressing a sum type in Varlink?

Comment: From https://varlink.org/Interface-Definition, Nullable type seems to be supported so `b: ?[]bool, i: ?[]int, s: ?[]string`, treating all as optional. you have to ensure only one is valid (you can get rid of the enum in the DSL).

Comment: @Jarod42: *From varlink.org/Interface-Definition, Nullable type seems to be
supported so b: ?[]bool, i: ?[]int, s: ?[]string, treating all as optional.*
But they’re not all optional. There always is a member with exactly one of the
variants. Sure I could just make them all optional and add runtime checks but
IMO that pretty much defeats the point of generating the serialization code from
interface definitions.

Comment: Alternative seems to be to send different "messages".